Unable to add user(s) to Farm Administrators group
I have some experience with SharePoint Online, but none with SharePoint Server and I’m trying to setup a local documentation server for material which should not be published online.
I’ve installed SharePoint Server Subscription in a simple two-server configuration – One SharePoint and one SQL server.
SQL server is set up with a gMSA and SharePoint is set up with a domain user with local admin permissions on the server, as well as the required permissions to the SQL server.
The SharePoint-admin user is a strictly local user – no MS365/Entra identity linked to it.
I thought I’d add a secondary user to the Farm Administrators group but it’s not working as I’m expecting it to.
When I try to add a user to the group, I add the e-mail address of the user in question and SharePoint can resolve that to an identity in the AD. I click that identity and choose to invite the user, but nothing happens. No email is sent/received, and the user never shows up in the Farm Administrators group.
At first, I thought the problem was that I hadn’t configured the SMTP settings in SharePoint, so I started by configuring that in SharePoint itself and pointing to our on-prem Exchange SMTP relay servers but that made no difference. Then I set up the SMTP service directly on the SharePoint server and tried again with no luck.
I also tested to send an email from the SharePoint server with the powershell Send-MailMessage cmdlet to see if there were issues with the firewalls or ports, but there was no problem sending or receiving that.
I set up an alert in SharePoint and immediately got a mail from ‘Central Administration’ that ‘System Account’ had subscribed me for the alert, which indicates that the SMTP is working as it should from SharePoint.
Am I going about this the wrong way?
Is there a reason why I’m unable to add a user to the Farm Administrators group?
Suggestions for moving forward are gratefully accepted.
Update 2024-07-11
I don't know why, but trying again I get a slightly different experience.
When I'm on the 'Peoples and groups > Farm Administrators' screen and click the button 'New' it drops down with the text 'Add users to this group'. This in turn, opens a dialog box with two tabs along the left side: 'Invite people' and 'Shared with'.
Going first to the 'Shared with'-tab and clicking 'Advanced' I get to a more detailed permissions page.
Clicking the 'Grant permissions'-button there I get an almost identical dialog box as previously, but expanding the 'Show options' text gives me two, rather than one option:

A checkbox for sending an email invitation
A dropdown for selecting permission level


This time when I try to add a user with the 'Share'-button on the dialog box i get an error message stating:

Sharing failed: Local Administrator privilege is required to update the Farm Administrator's group.
I was however able to add the user to the 'Delegated administrator'-group.

I will have to see if that is enough to be able to do what I need to do.
If I check the 'Send an email invitation'-box, I also actually receive an invitation now.

Are you not able to add the user to the farm administrators group directly, rather than sending an invitation?

@CallumCrowley - Sorry for the late reply. I updated with some new info and got a bit further along. Still unable to add the desired user to the Farm Administrator's group but got it in the Delegated Administrator's group instead.
